# Feature selection before ML (RF and SVM)

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, feature-selection, svm, lasso

I am new to machine learning and have to work with big data (lots of OTUs along with clinical) which I will input into 2 different machine learning models (**RF and SVM**) that will be used for prediction (**classification**). The number of samples is around 500.

My questions are:

1. Will it make sense to **apply a feature selection step** for RF and SVM?
2. Feature selection algorithms that come into mind are **RFE and LASSO**—planning to compare how well the two do. Will other techniques be better given the data and ML algorithms that will be used

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Edited the post to reduce the number of questions

Comment: Prediction is [vastly different from classification](https://fharrell.com/post/classification).   But to your main point it is a mistake to do supervised analysis before ML or statistical modeling.  That defeats the purpose and creates false confidence in the result.  I would do unsupervised learning as a first step thought (data reduction with the analysis not using Y).